# How do you change the appearance of a set theme in wordpress? How do you edit the code of the theme to change asterick to a different image?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I want to change an asterick in the theme "Twenty Twenty-Four" to a leaf image.

I don't know how to code, and I don't want to mess up my website. So if someone could explain in easier term.

I tried copying the clipping path of the image of the leaf I want, but I didnt do it correctly. I changed the editing visually to editing by code, and deleting and copying the clipping path. I am not sure where to delete and plug it in right.